# Where can I find mathematical formulas for plotting simple 3D objects?

Tags: graphing-functions, 3d

This may sound weird, but let's say I want to draw a banana or a bear using a library for 3D plotting of math functions (I am using manim but I expect the answer to not depend on the library).

Do you know if there are any resources for finding such formulas?

Comment: Try https://mathworld.wolfram.com/topics/AlgebraicSurfaces.html

Comment: This writeup might be helpful: https://medium.com/@catharine.r.lewis/how-to-graph-any-picture-739217a70539